# How to add responsive graphic logo to current "text logo"?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an image to my current text logo.  Right now the logo is 100% text and responsive, it resizes and all.  I need a logo or icon placed in front of it but it keeps resizing and lining up really weird.  Here is the current code that works with text only.  Trying to add a small 32 x 32 icon infant of the text and have it resize properly on mobile.

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        padding: 25px 0;
        -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
        -moz-transition: padding .3s;
        transition: padding .3s;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 2em;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s;
        -moz-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top.navbar-shrink {
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }


}
```

Here is what I have in the html file:

```
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">LOGO TEXT WORKING</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? There are many different options. You could create an image with the logo and text in the image and have that resize. Or you could set the height of the logo only image by vw. Like width:2vw;. Another option is creating a container for the logo image and have the container resize dynamically while the logo image is width:100%.

Or put both the img and text in a container so they always "line-up."